# Triggering the same jenkins job after the build is finished in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there a way to trigger the same job when the build is finished. I have one job that needed to be run until I aborted it manually. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: The simplest way would be to run it through the scheduler to run at regular intervals. You need to know how long it takes and adjust it accordingly. The job will not run at the same time as its previous run unless you specifically set it to and it will wait in the queue until it clears

Comment: You can use @KeepCalmAndCarryOn tip together with "Do not allow concurrent builds" and not worrying about how long it will run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty crazy request.  Are you sure that's what you want to do?  If you just want to keep up to date you could just have the job build when the SCM system changes- even down to using the filesystem as an SCM.

If you really want to do it though, it is possible.  You can't just tell it to trigger itself, but you can use the REST api.

Add a shell build step with the line

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/Tester/build
```

and a new job will get scheduled each time you run build.

Comment: The reason is I need to run these builds in some time interval continously. However this time interval is not fixed all the time. Plus I am curious about another stuff. Is there a way to run the same build continously. For example build is over and it will start again(build the code, run the test) without starting the new build

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're doing :)  In a traditional sense of a "build" though, repeating the build when the code hasn't changed doesn't accomplish very much. That's the only reason I asked.

Comment: I can see this being useful if the build has associated unit tests or system tests. The unit tests might be looking for a hardware glitch, or the system tests might subscribe to real-time data that update at varying times.

Comment: Any time you might be faced with fails that are both infrequent and intermittent, this is a good idea. I've used this in projects where both the HW and the SW were frequently updated, and it helped catch difficult problems more quickly.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do this is to add a post build step that builds the same project.  Set "Post-build Actions" - "Build other projects" - "Projects to build" to the name of your project and it will loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

There is "Build after other projects are built" under "Build Triggers" in job configuration page in which you can specify which project to build after which project. So if you want to continuously run a particular job, you can add Project name i.e your job name in "Projects to watch" field under "Build after other projects are built" and can run it with options :- Trigger only if build is stable
        Trigger even if the build is unstable
        Trigger even if the build fails

Comment: You just have to trigger it once after configuration is complete and it will run continuously

Answer (score 0):

you can try

1. add build step to create few files - file per condition set
2. add build step `Trigger/call builds on other projects` with `add parameter factories` with `For every matching file, invoke one build`
3. the called project might have input file as a parameter - it would be passed from the parent project from #2.